# Align Mathematical formulas

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I am writing my mathematical formulas and constraints with Overleaf. This is my code and I also show you the result I obtained (see picture). As you can see, the formulas are not well aligned. I would like to improve the layout by aligning all the formulas and having them labeled (with numbers, as it is shown in the picture). It would be extremely helpful if someone can help me with this!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newcommand{\mathgl}[2]{
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=2cm]
      \item[\gls{#1}]#2
    \end{description}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\begin{document}
\subsection{Stating the objective function} 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText

\begin{align}
\min \quad BFC \cdot \bigg(\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{i\in I}Fc_i \cdot u_i\bigg)
+ 
BEC \cdot \bigg(\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{i\in I}\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{j \in J}\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{p \in P}x_i_j_p\cdot Ec_i_j_p_y\bigg)
+
BTC \cdot \bigg(\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{i\in I}\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{j \in J}\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{p \in P}x_i_j_p\cdot Tc_i_j_p\bigg)
+
BWC \cdot \bigg(\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{i\in I}\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{j \in J}\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{p \in P}x_i_j_p\cdot Wc_i_j_p\bigg)
+
BZC \cdot \bigg(\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{i\in I}\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{j \in J}\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{p \in P}x_i_j_p\cdot Z_i_j_p\bigg)\cdot Zc 
\label{1}
\end{align}
 

\subsection{Stating the constraints}
The first constraint ensures that the demand of each customer is satisfied:

\begin{align}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}x_i_j_p = D_j_p_y,  \quad && \forall j \in J,  p\in P, y \in Y\label{2}
\end{align}
\noindent The second formula makes sure that the maximum capacity of each supplier facility is not exceeded:
\begin{align}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{j\in J}\mathlarger{\sum}_{p\in P}x_i_j_p \leq u_i,  \quad && \forall i \in I \label{3}
\end{align}
\noindent Contracts with specific supplier facilities may agree on minimum allocation volumes. This is ensured by the following formula:
\begin{align}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{j\in J}\mathlarger{\sum}_{p\in P}x_i_j_p \geq V_i,  \quad && \forall i \in I \label{3}
\end{align}
\noindent Specific breweries desire to be supplied by at least two suppliers for some specific type of product code. This is ensured by the following two formulas:
\begin{align}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}J_i_j_p \geq 2,  \quad && \forall j \in J,  p\in P \label{4}\\
x_i_j_p \geq b_i_j_p M_j_p
\end{align}
\noindentSpecific OpCos desire to be supplied by at least two suppliers for some specific type of product code. This is ensured by the following two formulas:
\begin{align}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}F_i_o_p\geq 2,\quad && \forall o \in O,  p\in P \label{5}\\
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\subset I}x_i_j_p \geq F_i_o_pG_o_p,\quad && \forall i \in I,  o\in O, p\in P \label{5}
\end{align}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to small but complete document which can be compiled as it is. In code you use commands from unknown source, so Document preamble, which is relevant to your problem, we need to see.

Comment: @Zarko I added the packages used in my document. Did you mean this?

Comment: @MaxLombaVrouenraets *Small* means as small as possible to show the problem. *Complete* means that the code compiles. Your edit does not do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution uses a single `align` environment and the `\intertext` command.

I simplified the preamble to what is necessary for the code to work. Also, I don't think you really need to use a double `\mathlarger`, which makes the equation number be placed under the equation, even when using `multlined`

B.t.w., you don't have to load `amsfonts`when you load `amssymb` – the latter does it for you. Note that `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{4}
\setcounter{subsection}{5}

\subsection{Stating the objective function}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
\min \quad BFC \cdot \bigg(\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}Fc_i \cdot u_i\bigg)
+
BEC \cdot \bigg(\mathop{\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}\mathlarger{\sum}_{j \in J}\mathlarger{\sum}_{p \in P}x_{i j p}}\cdot Ec_{ijpy}\bigg) +{}
\\
 BTC \cdot \bigg(\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}\mathlarger{\sum}_{j \in J}\mathlarger{\sum}_{p \in P}x_{ijp}\cdot Tc_{ijp}\bigg)
+
BWC \cdot \bigg(\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}\mathlarger{\sum}_{j \in J}\mathlarger{\sum}_{p \in P}x_{ijp}\cdot Wc_{ijp}\bigg)
\\
+ BZC \cdot \bigg(\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}\mathlarger{\sum}_{j \in J}\mathlarger{\sum}_{p \in P}x_{ijp}\cdot Z_{ijp}\bigg)\cdot Zc
\end{multlined}
\label{1}
  \end{equation}

\subsection{Stating the constraints}
The first constraint ensures that the demand of each customer is satisfied:

\begin{align}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}&x_{ijp} = D_{jpy}, \quad && \forall j \in J, p\in P, y \in Y\label{2} \\
\intertext{The second formula makes sure that the maximum capacity of each supplier facility is not exceeded:}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{j\in J}\mathlarger{\sum}_{p\in P} &x_{ijp} \leq u_i, \quad && \forall i \in I \label{3}
\intertext{Contracts with specific supplier facilities may agree on minimum allocation volumes. This is ensured by the following formula:}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{j\in J} \mathlarger{\sum}_{p\in P} &x_{ijp}\geq V_i, \quad && \forall i \in I \label{3} \\
\intertext{Specific breweries desire to be supplied by at least two suppliers for some specific type of product code. This is ensured by the following two formulas:}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}&J_{ijp} \geq 2, \quad && \forall j \in J, p\in P \label{4}\\
&x_{ijp} \geq b_{ijp} M_{jp}\\
\intertext{Specific OpCos desire to be supplied by at least two suppliers for some specific type of product code. This is ensured by the following two formulas:}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}&F_{iop} \geq 2,\quad && \forall o \in O, p\in P \label{5}\\
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\subset I}&x_{ijp} \geq F_{iop} G_{op},\quad && \forall i \in I, o\in O, p\in P \label{5}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for using a single `align` environment and several `\intertext` directives.

Comment: @Bernard +1 for your patience in cleaning the OP's code. Yet, I see little difference between your solution and mine.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an extended example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Let us try}
\subsection{Stating the objective function}

%\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}\label{1}
\begin{aligned}
\min \quad BFC  \bigg(\sum_{i\in I}Fc_i  u_i\bigg)
&+ BEC  \biggl(\sum_{i\in I} \sum_{j \in J} \sum_{p \in P} x_{ijp}  Ec_{ijp} y \biggr)    \\
&+ BTC  \biggl(\sum_{i\in I} \sum_{j \in J} \sum_{p \in P} x_{ijp}  Tc_{ijp}   \biggr)    \\
&+ BWC  \biggl(\sum_{i\in I} \sum_{j \in J} \sum_{p \in P} x_{ijp}  Wc_{ijp}   \biggr)    \\
&+ BZC  \biggl(\sum_{i\in I} \sum_{j \in J} \sum_{p \in P} x_{ijp}  Z_{ijp}    \biggr)  Zc
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}


\subsection{Stating the constraints}
The first constraint ensures that the demand of each customer is satisfied:

\begin{align}\label{2}\allowdisplaybreaks
&\sum_{i\in I} x_{ijp} = D_{jpy},  \quad && \forall j \in J,  p\in P, y \in Y\\
\intertext{The second formula makes sure that the maximum}
&\sum_{j\in J}\sum_{p\in P} x_{ijp} \leq u_i,  \quad && \forall i \in I \label{3}
\intertext{Specific breweries desire to be supplied by at least two suppliers for some specific type 
of product code. This is ensured by the following two formulas:}
&\sum_{i\in I}J_{ijp} \geq 2,  \quad && \forall j \in J,  p\in P \label{4}\\
&x_{ijp} \geq b_{ijp} M_{jp}\label{5}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

and see if the result suits you. If so, you can extend it easily.

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it by ten minutes! +1.

Comment: @MaxLombaVrouenraets Zarko's comment on `\cdot` is very well taken. My code should be modified accordingly.

Comment: @Zarko, thank you so much. This worked on my model! However, I get problems when I try to write two formulas after each other (in my picture, formulas 5 and 6). I try to separate them by using \\, however, the whole layout changes. How would you do it? I would be extremely grateful if you can extend your explanation until those two formulas.

Comment: @MaxLombaVrouenraets I have done so, although you confuse me with Zarko. If your code would compile, I could have given the whole example.

Comment: @MaxLombaVrouenraets Of course, I cannot guarantee that I have interpreted correctly your math formulae that does not compile. Check them.

Comment: @Davislor Sorry. I am still on holidays that(s why!

Comment: `\bigg(` should be `\biggl(` and `\bigg)` should be `\biggr)`

Comment: @egreg Right, of course. The starting code was so messy that I am not surprised that there are still bugs.

Answer (score 4):

My version, with no `\mathlarger`, reduced parentheses and a few other hints.

For instance, *BFC* and the similar symbols in the first display don't mean a product of three quantities, but a single variable, so `\mathit` reduces the spacing between the letters. Contrary to what others stated, `\cdot` is necessary in order to avoid the symbols be interpreted as “a function evaluated at”.

One should use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`, not just `\bigg`. Anyway, with the normal sized `\sum`, the `\Big` version seems better; add `\,` if the subscript can clash with the parenthesis.

Check the last `i\subset I`, which doesn't seem to fit.

You might consider

```
\sum_{\substack{i\in I \\ j\in J \\ p\in P}}
```

instead of the triple summation and similarly for the double summations.

Avoid blank lines before displays. There is no need for `\noindent` if there
is no blank line after the display (and if you have one, then `\noindent` would be wrong).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Stating the objective function} 

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text Text 
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\begin{split}
\min \tvar{BFC} &\cdot \Bigl(\,\sum_{i\in I} Fc_i \cdot u_i\Bigr)
+ 
\tvar{BEC} \cdot \Bigl(\,\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j \in J}\sum_{p \in P}x_{ijp} \tvar{Ec}_{ijpy}\Bigr)
\\
{}+
\tvar{BTC} &\cdot \Bigl(\,\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j \in J}\sum_{p \in P}x_{ijp} \tvar{Tc}_{ijp}\Bigr)
+
\tvar{BWC} \cdot \Bigl(\,\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j \in J}\sum_{p \in P}x_{ijp} \tvar{Wc}_{ijp}\Bigr)
\\
{}+
\tvar{BZC} &\cdot \Bigl(\,\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j \in J}\sum_{p \in P}x_{ijp} Z_{ijp}\Bigr) \tvar{Zc} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\subsection{Stating the constraints}
The first constraint ensures that the demand of each customer is satisfied:
\begin{equation}\label{2}
\sum_{i\in I}x_{ijp} = D_{jpy},  \quad \forall j \in J,  p\in P, y \in Y
\end{equation}
The second formula makes sure that the maximum capacity of each supplier facility 
is not exceeded:
\begin{equation}\label{3}
\sum_{j\in J}\sum_{p\in P}x_{ijp} \leq u_i,  \quad  \forall i \in I
\end{equation}
Contracts with specific supplier facilities may agree on minimum allocation volumes. 
This is ensured by the following formula:
\begin{equation}\label{4}
\sum_{j\in J}\sum_{p\in P}x_{ijp} \geq V_i,  \quad \forall i \in I
\end{equation}
Specific breweries desire to be supplied by at least two suppliers for some specific 
type of product code. This is ensured by the following two formulas:
\begin{equation}\label{5}
\sum_{i\in I}J_{ijp} \geq 2,  \quad \forall j \in J,  p\in P
x_{ijp} \geq b_{ijp} M_{jp}
\end{equation}
Specific OpCos desire to be supplied by at least two suppliers for some specific 
type of product code. This is ensured by the following two formulas:
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\sum_{i\in I}F_{iop}\geq 2, &\quad& \forall o \in O,  p\in P \label{6}\\
&\sum_{i\subset I}x_{ijp} \geq F_{iop}G_{op}, && \forall i \in I,  o\in O, p\in P \label{7}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the version with `\substack`

[image]

Comment: I like the use of `split` here, but the question asked for all the formulas to be aligned, and this does not seem to do that.

Answer (score 3):

For the first equation you can use `multline` environment (defined in the `amsmath` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Stating the objective function}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{multline}\label{1}
\min \quad \mathrm{BFC}{\cdot}\bigg(\sum_{i\in I}Fc_i{\cdot} u_i\bigg)
+ \mathrm{BEC}{\cdot}\bigg(\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j \in J}\sum_{p \in P}x_{ijp}{\cdot}Ec_{ijpy}\bigg)  \\
%
+ \mathrm{BTC}{\cdot}\bigg(\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j \in J}\sum_{p \in P}x_{ijp}{\cdot}Tc_{ijp}\bigg)
+ \mathrm{BWC}{\cdot}\bigg(\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j \in J}\sum_{p \in P}x_{ijp}{\cdot}Wc_{ijp}\bigg)   \\
%
+ \mathrm{BZC}{\cdot}\bigg(\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j \in J}\sum_{p \in P}x_{ijp}{\cdot}Z_{ijp}\bigg){\cdot}Zc
\end{multline}
\end{document}

\subsection{Stating the constraints}
The first constraint ensures that the demand of each customer is satisfied:

\begin{align}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}x_i_j_p = D_j_p_y,  \quad && \forall j \in J,  p\in P, y \in Y\label{2}
\end{align}
\noindent The second formula makes sure that the maximum capacity of each supplier facility is not exceeded:
\begin{align}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{j\in J}\mathlarger{\sum}_{p\in P}x_i_j_p \leq u_i,  \quad && \forall i \in I \label{3}
\end{align}
\noindent Contracts with specific supplier facilities may agree on minimum allocation volumes. This is ensured by the following formula:
\begin{align}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{j\in J}\mathlarger{\sum}_{p\in P}x_i_j_p \geq V_i,  \quad && \forall i \in I \label{3}
\end{align}
\noindent Specific breweries desire to be supplied by at least two suppliers for some specific type of product code. This is ensured by the following two formulas:
\begin{align}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}J_i_j_p \geq 2,  \quad && \forall j \in J,  p\in P \label{4}\\
x_i_j_p \geq b_i_j_p M_j_p
\end{align}
\noindentSpecific OpCos desire to be supplied by at least two suppliers for some specific type of product code. This is ensured by the following two formulas:
\begin{align}
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\in I}F_i_o_p\geq 2,\quad && \forall o \in O,  p\in P \label{5}\\
\mathlarger{\sum}_{i\subset I}x_i_j_p \geq F_i_o_pG_o_p,\quad && \forall i \in I,  o\in O, p\in P \label{5}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Some comments:

- Increasin size of some symbols in equation (in your case `\sum`) is not good idea. Their size are deliberately crafted for nice looking equations, so please don't destroy designers efforts
- I suppose that `BFC`, `BTC`, etc are abbreviations, which should be write with upshape fonts, i.e. it should be writen as `\mathrm{BFC}`, `\mathbf{BTC}˙, etc
- Similarly `c_i_j_p_y` is wrong notation. It should be or `c_{ijpy}` (which result is the most probably desired) or `c_{i_{j_{p_{y}}}}` (which is less likely)
- From mathematical point the use of `\cdot` for multiplication is not needed. Anyway, if you persist to use them, than you can reduce space around them with enclosing them in curly braces (as is done in above MWE)

Comment: thank you for your comments. Good to know about the \cdot trick. On the other hand, I do not like the layout of the multline (the label number appears at the end). I think the layout of your first answer is much more beautiful :)

Comment: @MaxLombaVrouenraets, well, to me is mine solution nicer (and correct) :-)